# Https - Token becomes invalid after internet disconnection?

Tags: security, http, authentication, ssl, https

The question may sound silly, but it has been long since I dealt with security issues on the web.

If a user logs in and gets a token that's valid for 30 minutes. After a few minutes, he disconnects the internet. Before the 30 minutes window is closed, he re-connects again. Is the previous token in still valid?

For clarity, does authentication depend on combination of token and user credentials OR token and IP?

Comment: There are a number of things that could be a "token" and whether or not they are valid after disconnection depends on the technology used. Could you perhaps add some detail about the situation you are concerned about, as I don't think the question is answerable in its current form.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have more details. All I have is user credentials and as I log in, I receive a token for further requests to the server. What's required is NOT to renew the token even if the user goes offline. Renewal is based only on token renewal period. (30 mins)

Comment: If the "token" is matched to an IP address, then when the user reconnect to the internet, and (i'm assuming) gets a new IP address, then the old token-IP pair will not be valid, because the IP will have changed

Answer (score 1):

If you truly have no information about the technology used and no way of getting it, I would suggest just trying it out.

Be the user yourself, try to disconnect, try to change your IP etc.

But the best bet is still tot try to get hold of what technology is used.

Answer (score 1):

First to state the obvious: other than a (possible) change in IP address, there is no way for the server to know that the client disconnected/reconnected, or just stayed connected all the time.

Usually tokens are not bound to strict IP addresses. This is because sometimes subsequent connections come from different IP addresses (it might be routed through loadbalanced proxy servers, even in this day and age some people still use them/ some ISPs still implement them), or some other way how the IP address might change. That being said, my experience is that in these cases the "subnet" remain the same (so in XXX.XXX.XXX.YYY, YYY may change between requests, the X's stay the same. Not sure how this id for IPv6). So, I know some systems bind the token to the 24 Most Significant Bits, to avoid token hijacking (if someone gets hold of your token for whatever reason, they will need to connect from the same subnet for the token to be valid).

In the end it all depends on the system. It should be easy enough to check. Log in on your laptop to the site. Then, leaving the browser open, connect through some VPN (anonymizer), connect your laptop through phone tethering, or ask to use the neighbours / local coffee shop's wifi, and see if you're still logged in.

Comment: If the behavior is wanted then the server could check if the browser has been closed by defining a cookie that is removed when the browser is closed.